# How do I change images using OnClick?

Tags: javascript, image, for-loop, onclick, getelementbyid

I have 7 images, it starts in 0 and I want to change them one by one each time I click on the image.

This is what I have so far:

```
function changePic() {
    var img = new Array("1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png", "6.png");
        for(var p=0; p<6; p++) {
            document.getElementById("image").src=img[p]; 
        }                   
}
```

HTML: img onclick="changePic()" src="0.png"  id="image"/

The problem is that it changes everything at once, so it skips from img 0 to 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the `src` 6 times with each click.  You want to do it once, and increment a counter outside the function:

```
var imgs = new Array("1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png", "6.png");
var index = 0;
function changePic() {
    document.getElementById('image').src = imgs[index];
    index++;
    if ( index >= imgs.length ) index = 0;
}
```

You may want a closure, to reduce global namespace goop.  Just be careful to define it before your HTML `<img>`:

```
var changePic = (function(imgs) {
    var index = 0;
    return function changePic() {
        document.getElementById('image').src = imgs[index++];
        if ( index >= imgs.length ) index = 0;
    }
})(["1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png", "6.png"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the loop, and do something like this..

```
   var currentPic=0;
   function changePic() {
        var img = new Array("1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png", "6.png");                           
           document.getElementById("image").src=img[currentPic]; 
           currentPic++;   
           if(currentPic > 5) {currentPic=0;}              
    }
```

Comment: It may help him to only define `img` once?

Comment: true, just wanted to make minimum changes to her code so she gets her mistake. your 1st code is nice ! upvoted !